# jQuery syntax using "not" with uniform plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am puzzled by the reference to the word 'not' in the following code:

```
$("select, input[type=file]").not('select[multiple]').uniform();
```

Could someone please explain it for me?

Comment: when in doubt go to jQuery API and type method name in search box. Will autofilter right in page as you type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [.not() method](http://api.jquery.com/not/). It removes any elements from the current matched set that match the given selector.

The initial jQuery call selects all the `<select>` and `<input type="file">` elements on the page. The `.not()` specifically excludes any `<select>` elements with the `multiple` attribute, removing them before the `.uniform()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Makes perfect sense.